# Guardar una cadena que devuelve una función en una variable

Tags: c++

¿Alguien sabe como guardar en una variable, una cadena que devuelve una función?
En este caso lo que quiero hacer es que, lo que devuelve *system("date /t");* (Que devuelve una fecha en el siguiente formato; *Thu 04/04/2019*) quede guardado en una variable para después hacer que el programa reconozca cuando paso un dia y es una fecha diferente.

```
int main(){
  FreeConsole();
  string date[12]=system("date /t"); /* Esto me da error */

  recon_task();
}
```

Comment: `system( )` **no devuelve una cadena**, devuelve el código de salida del ejecutable externo. Lo que quieres hacer es **muy** distinto. Te recomiendo que guardes la salida en un archivo ( `system( "date /t > date.out" );` ) y lo leeas desde C++.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda :) entonces en definitiva tengo que usar las funciones del header <string.h> para leerlo desde C++ y recién ahí lo puedo  guardar en una variable? Lo único que me interesa es poder comparar

Comment: Tienes que usar `<fstream>`, en concreto `std::ifstream`. Hay muchos [ejemplos, artículos y cursos en internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+lectura+archivos+ifstream&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) de lectura de archivos en C++.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya puedo dar por concluida la pregunta pero no puedo votar te como mejor respuesta, me falta popularidad jajaja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Alguien sabe como guardar en una variable, una cadena que devuelve una función?

Es muy fácil, teniendo una función que devuelve una cadena:

```
std::string cadena() { return "Hola Mundo!\n"; }
```

Puedes guardarla así:

```
std::string variable = cadena();
```

---

Tu problema es que [`std::sytem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) no devuelve una cadena y aunque así fuera, `string date[12]` no es una cadena, son doce cadenas en una formación<sup>1</sup>. Lo que hace la función `std::system` es llamar a un comando del sistema operativo; los efectos que tenga dicho comando son transparentes a tu programa, así que no puedes leer nada de lo que dicho comando muestre por pantalla (si es que muestra algo).

Lo que si puedes hacer, es redirigir la salida del comando a un archivo, y luego leer dicho archivo:

```
std::system("date /t > archivo.txt");

if (std::ifstream archivo{"archivo.txt"})
{
    std::string fecha;
    archivo >> fecha;
    std::cout << fecha;
}
```

Pero, sinceramente, es una manera absurda de obtener la fecha del sistema, es mucho más fácil usar la cabecera [`<chrono>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono):

```
using namespace std::chrono;
auto ahora = system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now());
std::cout << std::ctime(&ahora);
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/X5GWWPX3ecDRycif).

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, bueno supongo que en parte el problema que tengo es que no se como plantear bien mi problema, el motivo por el cual quiero obtener la fecha en una variable es para poder hacer que mi programa sepa cuando pasó un dia, y en base a eso pueda limitarse a escribir la fecha en el archivo donde registra eventos solo una vez, igualmente tu respuesta me sirve muchisimo :) Obtener la fecha mediante la lectura de un archivo no me parece tan absurdo a mi, despues de todo mi keylogger escribe todo en un archivo xD

Comment: @Phantom'Conqueror' si esta respuesta te sirvio, podrias darla como aceptada? usa el tilde debajo de la cantidad de votos en la respuesta

Comment: @Phantom'Conqueror' si quieres saber cuánto tiempo ha pasado, no necesitas volcar un comando en un archivo para leer el archivo en modo texto y transformar dicho texto en una fecha. Basta con usar las utilidades de la cabecera `<chrono>`.

Comment: Ya la di como aceptada, perdon es que soy nuevo en esto de Stack Overflow :)